# Generating unique IDs for types at compile time

Tags: rust

I want to generate a unique id for every type at compile time. Is this possible in Rust?

So far, I have the following code

```
//Pseudo code
struct ClassTypeId{
    id: &'static uint
}
impl ClassTypeId{
    fn get_type<T>(&mut self) -> &'static uint {
        let _id :&'static uint = self.id + 1;
        self.id = _id;
        _id
    }
}

let c = ClassTypeId{id:0};
c.get_type::<i32>();  // returns 1
c.get_type::<f32>();  // returns 2
c.get_type::<i32>();  // returns 1
c.get_type::<uint>(); // returns 3
```

I stole this idea from a C++ library, which looks like this

```
typedef std::size_t TypeId;

        template <typename TBase>
        class ClassTypeId
        {
        public:

            template <typename T>
            static TypeId GetTypeId()
            {
                static const TypeId id = m_nextTypeId++;
                return id;
            }

        private:

            static TypeId m_nextTypeId;
        };

        template <typename TBase>
        TypeId ClassTypeId<TBase>::m_nextTypeId = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What about simply using [`typeid()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)?

Comment: Why do you want this? What’s your use case?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Short answer: Entity Component System. I want to create a bitmask for every component, so that I can easily filter components at runtime.`for(entity: world.filter(Position,Velocity)){}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`std::any::TypeId`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) does something like that:

```
use std::any::TypeId;

fn main() {
    let type_id = TypeId::of::<isize>();
    println!("{:?}", type_id);
}
```

outputs:

```
TypeId { t: 4150853580804116396 }
```

Answer (score 8):

This sounds like a job for the bitflags! macro:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rustc_bitflags;

bitflags!(
    #[derive(Debug)]
    flags ComponentMask: u8 {
        const Render     = 0b00000001,
        const Position   = 0b00000010,
        const Physics    = 0b00000100
    }
);

// the set of components owned by an entity:
let owned_components:  = Render | Position;

// check whether an entity has a certain component:
if owned_components.contains(Physics) { ... }
```

http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc_bitflags/macro.bitflags!.html

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do, just that I want to achieve this automatically at compile time.

Comment: Maybe I can create this with a macro `add_flag!(Position)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage type ids manually, you can use my [unique-type-id crate](https://crates.io/crates/unique-type-id). It allows you to specify what ids a type has in a special file. It will generate them at compile time. Currently it can be used in this way:

```
use unique_type_id::UniqueTypeId;
#[derive(UniqueTypeId)]
struct Test1;
#[derive(UniqueTypeId)]
struct Test2;

assert_eq!(Test1::id().0, 1u64);
assert_eq!(Test2::id().0, 2u64);
```

It can both generate types using incremental number and use the id from a file.

Answer (score 0):

`TypeId` may meet some needs, but for one of my projects, I spent some time looking for a shareable identification solution whose consistency I could really control over time. The crates I found didn't completely satisfy me, so I wrote my own: `hashed-type-def`.

The [`hashed-type-def`](https://crates.io/crates/hashed-type-def) trait generates a constant hash code of the type in `u128` format at compile time.
The hash code generated by the derive macro is built from the morphology of the type definition and does not depend on the rust version.

As the crate uses a procedural macro, however, the result could depend on the sequences generated by the parser (`syn`) and therefore on the evolution of this parser.

Example of use:

```
use hashed_type_def::HashedTypeDef;

#[derive(HashedTypeDef)]
struct MyStruct<'a,'b,T,U,const C1: usize, const C2: bool> where T: Into<U> + 'b, 'a: 'b {
    #[allow(dead_code)] un: &'a String,
    #[allow(dead_code)] deux: T,
    #[allow(dead_code)] trois: &'b U,
}
fn main() {
    println!("MyStruct::<'static,'static,f32,f64,12,true>::TYPE_HASH_NATIVE");
    println!("   -> {}", MyStruct::<'static,'static,f32,f64,12,true>::TYPE_HASH_NATIVE);
}
```

Result:

```
MyStruct::<'static,'static,f32,f64,12,true>::TYPE_HASH_NATIVE
   -> 108441525295622464281107308054093424330
```

Comment: Is this crate yours? If yes, you are obliged to [disclose your affiliation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Okay, I've completed my answer.