# Create a map using type as key

Tags: rust

I need a `HashMap<K,V>` where V is a trait (it will likely be Box or an Rc or something, that's not important), and I need to ensure that the map stores at most one of a given struct, and more importantly, that I can query the presence of (and retrieve/insert) items by their type.  K can be anything that is unique to each type (a uint would be nice, but a String or even some large struct holding type information would be sufficient as long as it can be `Eq` and `Hash`able)

This is occurring in a library, so I cannot use an enum or such since new types can be added by external code.

I looked into `std::any::TypeId` but besides not working for non-`'static` types, it seems they [aren't even unique](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10389) (and allegedly collisions were achieved accidentally with a rather small number of types) so I'd prefer to avoid them if feasible since the number of types I'll have may be very large. (hence this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372477/generating-unique-ids-for-types-at-compile-time) IMO)

I'd like something along the lines of a macro to ensure uniqueness but I can't figure out how to have some kind of global compile time counter.  I could use a proper UUID, but it'd be nice to have *guaranteed* uniqueness since this is, in theory at least, statically determinable.

It is safe to assume that all relevant types are defined either in this lib or in a singular crate that directly depends on it, if that allows for a solution that might be otherwise impossible.

e.g. my thoughts are to generate ids for types in the lib, and also export a constant of the counter, which can be used by the consumer of the lib in the same macro (or a very similar one) but I don't see a way to have such a const value modified by const code in multiple places.

Is this possible or do I need some kind of build script that provides values before compile time?

Comment: >in theory at least, statically determinable.
I think, it determinable only in one translation unit due to monomorphization :(

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros you may be right.  This may only be doable in rust via std::any::TypeID... which has a soundness bug

Comment: I found that gotham.rs developers use TypeId: https://github.com/gotham-rs/gotham/blob/89c491fb4322bbc6fbcc8405c3a33e0634f7cbba/gotham/src/state/mod.rs#L48

Comment: I caved and went with typeid, if I run into collisions I'll deal with it then.  For anyone else looking into this, I believe a solution would be possible via e.g. the ctor crate (look into how serde typetag uses it perhaps)